# `block (2 levels) in load' exception when running capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

Yesterday an unwelcomed visitor was mucking around my server. I since rebooted ubuntu and changed passwords. Now I try to deploy my rails application and I am getting an error.

Here is the important part:

```
 ** [out :: 172.27.12.xxx] /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
 ** [out :: 172.27.12.xxx] /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
 ** [out :: 172.27.12.xxx] /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /home/guarddog/public_html/guarddog.com/releases/20131220150214; true"
    servers: ["172.27.12.xxx", "172.27.12.xxx", "172.27.12.xxx"]
 ** [deploy:update_code] exception while rolling back: IOError, closed stream
```

This is stack trace of error:

```
Users/guarddog/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/net-ssh-2.6.2/lib/net/ssh/buffered_io.rb:65:in `recv': Operation timed out - recvfrom(2) (Errno::ETIMEDOUT)
    from /Users/guarddog/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/net-ssh-2.6.2/lib/net/ssh/buffered_io.rb:65:in `fill'
    from /Users/guarddog/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/net-ssh-2.6.2/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:228:in `block in postprocess'
    from /Users/guarddog/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/net-ssh-2.6.2/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:224:in `each'
    from /Users/guarddog/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/net-ssh-2.6.2/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:224:in `postprocess'
    from /Users/guarddog/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/processable.rb:31:in `block in process_iteration'
    from /Users/guarddog/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/processable.rb:43:in `block in ensure_each_session'
    from /Users/guarddog/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/processable.rb:41:in `each'
    from /Users/guarddog/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/processable.rb:41:in `ensure_each_session'
    from /Users/guarddog/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/processable.rb:29:in `process_iteration'
    from /Users/guarddog/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/command.rb:165:in `block (2 levels) in process!'
    from /Users/guarddog/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/command.rb:164:in `loop'
    from /Users/guarddog/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/command.rb:164:in `block in process!'
    from /Users/guarddog/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:295:in `realtime'
    from /Users/guarddog/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/command.rb:163:in `process!'
    from /Users/guarddog/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/command.rb:134:in `process'
    from /Users/guarddog/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/actions/invocation.rb:185:in `block in run_tree'
    from /Users/guarddog/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/connections.rb:198:in `block in execute_on_servers'
    from /Users/guarddog/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/connections.rb:186:in `each'
    from /Users/guarddog/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/connections.rb:186:in `each_slice'
    from /Users/guarddog/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/connections.rb:186:in `execute_on_servers'
    from /Users/guarddog/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/actions/invocation.rb:183:in `run_tree'
    from /Users/guarddog/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/actions/invocation.rb:155:in `run'
    from /Users/guarddog/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/namespaces.rb:191:in `method_missing'
    from ./config/deploy.rb:77:in `block (2 levels) in load'
    from /Users/guarddog/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:138:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/guarddog/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:138:in `invoke_task_directly'
    from /Users/guarddog/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/callbacks.rb:25:in `invoke_task_directly_with_callbacks'
    from /Users/guarddog/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:89:in `execute_task'
    from /Users/guarddog/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:101:in `find_and_execute_task'
    from /Users/guarddog/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/callback.rb:38:in `call'
    from /Users/guarddog/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/callbacks.rb:141:in `block in trigger'
    from /Users/guarddog/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/callbacks.rb:141:in `each'
    from /Users/guarddog/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/callbacks.rb:141:in `trigger'
    from /Users/guarddog/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/callbacks.rb:27:in `invoke_task_directly_with_callbacks'
    from /Users/guarddog/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:89:in `execute_task'
    from /Users/guarddog/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/namespaces.rb:191:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/guarddog/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/namespaces.rb:110:in `block in define_task'
    from /Users/guarddog/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy.rb:228:in `block (3 levels) in load'
    from /Users/guarddog/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:56:in `transaction'
    from /Users/guarddog/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/namespaces.rb:191:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/guarddog/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy.rb:227:in `block (2 levels) in load'
    from /Users/guarddog/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:138:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/guarddog/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:138:in `invoke_task_directly'
    from /Users/guarddog/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/callbacks.rb:25:in `invoke_task_directly_with_callbacks'
    from /Users/guarddog/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:89:in `execute_task'
    from /Users/guarddog/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/namespaces.rb:191:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/guarddog/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/namespaces.rb:110:in `block in define_task'
    from /Users/guarddog/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy.rb:195:in `block (2 levels) in load'
    from /Users/guarddog/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:138:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/guarddog/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:138:in `invoke_task_directly'
    from /Users/guarddog/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/callbacks.rb:25:in `invoke_task_directly_with_callbacks'
    from /Users/guarddog/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:89:in `execute_task'
    from /Users/guarddog/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:101:in `find_and_execute_task'
    from /Users/guarddog/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:46:in `block in execute_requested_actions'
    from /Users/guarddog/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:45:in `each'
    from /Users/guarddog/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:45:in `execute_requested_actions'
    from /Users/guarddog/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/cli/help.rb:19:in `execute_requested_actions_with_help'
    from /Users/guarddog/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:34:in `execute!'
    from /Users/guarddog/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:14:in `execute'
    from /Users/guarddog/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/bin/cap:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/guarddog/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/cap:19:in `load'
    from /Users/guarddog/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/cap:19:in `<main>'
```

I think the notable part is this line:

```
from ./config/deploy.rb:77:in `block (2 levels) in load'
```

That's actual code in my deploy.rb file:

```
task :precompile, :role => :app do
  run "cd #{release_path}/ && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile"
end
```

which is executed because of this line in my deploy.rb:

```
after "deploy:update_code", "deploy:precompile"
```

Note the deploys were working fine until the incident happened yesterday. He seemed to clone the git repository and copy it somewhere. But he didn't seem to delete any files.

Any idea why deploy:precompile gives the error?

Comment: By an _unwelcome visitor_, do you mean someone you know who was just looking around, or someone unknown hacked into the account?  I ask, because if it was the latter, I would consider this server exploited and do a complete reinstall.  There could be rootkits or other nasty things going on that you may not be aware of.

Comment: @Donovan I know who it is, and I believe they were just looking around because I ran the history command and didn't see anything other than them cloning my repository to theirs, because apparently they wanted to see my code. I since changed passwords. But I don't think they done harm.

Comment: What happens when you manually run `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`?

Comment: Also, does git show any files that may have been modified, `git status`?

Comment: @Donovan should I run "RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile" in the current directory or in the releases directory for the current release?

Comment: either or both.  The idea is to make sure it runs without an error.

Comment: @Donovan I ran it on the server and it didn't give me any error

Comment: What about other modifications to your code that you may not be aware of?  (e.g. what does `git status` show you?)

Comment: @Donovan there are some untracked files on the deploy branch, but those been there for some time and have not had any effect. It seems no files were modified after he logged in yesterday.

Comment: Hmmm... it seems very odd that this deployment was working until this _unwelcomed_ visitor came along.  Have you tried a cold deploy?  `cap deploy:cold`

Comment: @Donovan the website is actually currently running without problems. Should I still do a cold deploy?

Comment: Well, only you can answer that.  a cold deploy won't modify your database, it just doesn't try to push only changes.

Comment: @Donovan any idea why it would say `block (2 levels) in load'. Why such an error occurs in my project? It doesn't seem that run "cd #{release_path}/ && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile" should produce such an error

Comment: heh, that's the $20,000 question, isn't it?  If I had a good answer for you, I would have posted it instead of asking questions in the comments.  ;-)  I _suspect_ something happened to your code on the remote server.

Comment: @Donovan When I run git status on deploy branch, I see this: # Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
# REVISION
# log
# public/assets/
# public/system

Comment: Yea, so maybe someone monkeyed with your remote codebase?  `deploy:cold` should fix that issue.  I'll put that in an answer, since this comment thread is getting very long.  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your remote codebase may have been compromised.  I suggest using

```
cap deploy:check
cap deploy:cleanup
cap deploy:cold
```

to redeploy a fresh copy of your original codebase.

This will not modify your remote database, but it will restart the remote httpd server so, as with any deploy, you should wait until a suitable maintenance window to try it.

Comment: I read the documentation. It says deploy:cold "instead of invoking 'deploy:restart', it will invoke 'deploy:start' to fire up
the application servers." What exactly is the difference here? Just so I am cleared, you said some of code might be comprised. Will a cap deploy:cold take my local copy and copy it into the server and copy over anything that could be compromised?

Comment: Yes, generally speaking.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a few more things you can check/try.  In the past, when I've had problems deploying, these steps helped resolve the issues.

Comment: just in case something does happen where the site goes down because of this, is there a command to revert it to the previous state  ?

Comment: Here's a good list of the Capistrano deploy commands: http://wiki.brightbox.co.uk/docs:gemv2:capistrano

Comment: Hey, I deleted all the ssh keys and generated new ones, and then deployed again and it worked. I am not sure if it was that or running "RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile" that made it work. But I deployed and it gave no error. I am going to try again in 5 hours and if it breaks again, then I will try the answer suggested here.